# How do I fight Omega Flowey a second time?

Tags: undertale

I want to fight Omega Flowey again, but I already fought him.

Can I fight Omega Flowey on a subsequent playthrough? If so, how?

Comment: Did you kill or spare flowey?

Comment: @Vemonus I spared Flowey. I didn't kill Flowey.

Comment: Then was it a pacifist or neutral route game? Also are you asking about fighting Flowey twice in a single playthrough or fighting him again in a later playthrough?

Comment: I played neutral route game.

Comment: For someone who only watched a Let's Play of undertale, care to explain what 'Photoshop Flowey' means?

Comment: I think he is referring to Omega Flowey, AKA MSPaint Flowey. Never heard it called Photoshop Flowey.

Comment: Omega Flowey is the official boss name, but Photoshop Flowey is a fan-favorite nickname due to the boss' art style, which is dramatically different from anything else in the game.

Comment: I through Photoshop Flowey is official name! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wikia page on Flowey](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Flowey):

> **If the protagonist loads or finishes another Neutral Route, Flowey does not absorb the SOULs because he knows that they would rebel again.** Instead, the protagonist will be able to exit the room and receive Sans's Neutral Route phone call.

Due to the part I bolded, you will not be able to fight Flowey in another Neutral Route playthrough without doing the following, based on [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/391540/discussions/0/458605613406806779/).

> Date Papyrus and befriend Undyne. Then Undyne will give you a letter. Give it to Alphys and go to her lab to find a new level. After completing it you'll get a new ending. After that ending, you can do a True Reset to fight Flowey again.

Thus, to fight Flowey again in a Neutral playthrough, you will need to perform a True Reset, which apparently can only be done after completing a True Pacifist playthrough. (See [here](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/SAVE))

> A True Reset is a function available after completing the True Pacifist Route. It thoroughly erases all of the information stored in the SAVE file, with one exception: If the Genocide Route is completed, the First Human destroys the world and its timelines. They then offer the player to recreate the world in exchange for their SOUL. Accepting this offer is similar to a True Reset; however, accepting this offer also activates a permanent flag in the game's files, which affects the outcome of the True Pacifist Route.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fight Flowey again, but don't want to start the entire game over again from the beginning, you can use the aptly named [Flowey's Time Machine](https://crumblingstatue.github.io/FloweysTimeMachine/).

It lets you customize your Undertale save file however you'd like, meaning you create a save file that puts you right before the fight with Omega Flowey.